# Chartjs Radar chart - How to dynamically highlight one of the gridlines at a specific point

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I create a radar chart to display data which comes from my backend. The data is dynamic, but I would like to highlight the gridline at 60 as shown below. Does chartjs have any solution to achieve it?

```js
const gray = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
const color = Chart.helpers.color;
const config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [['Eating', 'Dinner'], ['Drinking', 'Water'], 'Sleeping', ['Designing', 'Graphics'], 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My dataset',
      backgroundColor: color(gray).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
      borderColor: gray,
      pointBackgroundColor: gray,
      data: [
        80,
        90,
        60,
        65,
        78,
        97,
        55
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        circular: true,
        color: [gray, gray, 'blue', gray, gray, gray, gray, gray, gray, gray]
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepsize: 20
        
      },
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function () {
  window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), config);
};
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Since your `data` is dynamic, you need to compute scale.gridLines.colors based on the `data`. This could be done as follows:

```
const data = [80, 90, 60, 65, 78, 97, 55];
const gridLinesStepSize = 20;
const highlightedGridLine = 60;
const gridLineColors = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(Math.max(...data) / gridLinesStepSize) + 1).keys())
  .map(n => n * 20)
  .slice(1)
  .map(v => v == highlightedGridLine ? 'blue' : gray);
```

Please take a look at your amended runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const gray = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
const color = Chart.helpers.color;

const data = [80, 90, 60, 65, 78, 97, 55];
const gridLinesStepSize = 20;
const highlightedGridLine = 60;
const gridLineColors = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(Math.max(...data) / gridLinesStepSize) + 1).keys())
  .map(n => n * 20)
  .slice(1)
  .map(v => v == highlightedGridLine ? 'blue' : gray);

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      ['Eating', 'Dinner'],
      ['Drinking', 'Water'], 'Sleeping', ['Designing', 'Graphics'], 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My dataset',
      backgroundColor: color(gray).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
      borderColor: gray,
      pointBackgroundColor: gray,
      data: data
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        circular: true,
        color: gridLineColors
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepsize: gridLinesStepSize
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="120"></canvas>
```